# ScrollTop() Not Working

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I'm struggling to get scrolltop() to return a value. Right now it just gives 0. I know it's a simple issue but does anyone have any advice?

Here's the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').scroll(function(){
var body = $("body");
var top = body.scrollTop()
$('p').text(top)
});
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<p>Top value will go here</p>
<div style='height:2000px'/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Attach the `scroll()` event to the window instead of the body. The window likely has the scrollbar that you're scrolling:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    ....
```

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't even register (an alert did not trigger).

Comment: Hello again, just to let you know, the exact same code now seems to be working, thanks for your help all the same!

Comment: @FinMoorhouse awesome! I forgot to mention that you should use `$(window).scrollTop()` as well, but I'm glad it's working!